# Does this birchas habeit have any forbidden images?

Tags: halacha

[image]

I’m wondering if this print is completely kosher, since I wanted to gift it. I don’t see any stars (except two magen Avrahums), sun, moon, or full images of malachim (although there seems to be two) or full human features. But wanted everyone’s input here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Like any library, Mi Yodeya offers tons of great information, but _[does not offer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734) personalized, professional advice_, and does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146).

Comment: For starters, the top of the image appears to show two yellow hamsas, which I believe are assumed to have originated as pagan fertility symbols.